# Can't update or install apps on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-one

For some reason whenever I try to update or install an app via the store, Ubuntu Touch keeps asking for my Ubuntu One account, but logging in doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem in my case:

I rebooted and left the phone off overnight.

I also had to add my Ubuntu One account again in **Settings**, then in  **Accounts**.