# Unable to log into my Ubuntu One account

Tags: ubuntu-one

Last night and today, I have been unable to download any apps or scopes, as I am have been unable to log into my Ubuntu One account. I left it over night and today I even reset my account. Is there any problems with Ubuntu One and the app store as it would appear that my account isfine.?

Comment: A what question? I have found out that I can log into my account when I go via the updates in settings, but cannot log in when I try via the Ubuntu Store.

Comment: I have had this issue before in the past. What I have done (not very scientific) is leave it overnight and then in the morning it was OK. It has worked for me. However, i would imagine that now you are back in OK as it has been a bit since you posted this.

Comment: Thanks unknown user for your helpful comments. I have been able to log into my account since leaving it a bit longer.

Comment: This happened the other night again. I wonder if this is due to the fact that I have a number of devices running the same account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't update or install apps on Ubuntu Touch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761603/cant-update-or-install-apps-on-ubuntu-touch)